# avconv crashes after ~3 minutes - could be source regression, how do I get last stable version in git?

Tags: git, pulse-audio, libav

```
Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 1: 8657 >= 8657
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
[pulse @ 0x2a03400] pa_simple_read failed: Bad state
Assertion 'pa_atomic_load(&(s)->_ref) >= 1' failed at pulse/stream.c:335, function pa_stream_get_state(). Aborting.
```

Last time this happened that last line wasn't there, and the file was corrupted but openable.

I `git clone`d the source from the avconv git repo, that's probably why it's not working properly. How do I get the source for the last stable release in git? (My idea of version control is `apt-get source`)

I downloaded a "release" source and compiled it but I can't test it as it's giving me:

```
Preset lossless_ultrafast specified for stream 0:0, but could not be opened.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "Release" version of libav did the trick, but I had to put my presets in `~/.avconv` as the older version presets weren't compatible with the newer build.